# Can I reference the git repo from a repo-level .gitconfig file for a custom binary-file diff handler?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-config

I need to diff Excel files, so I found [this](https://github.com/tokuhirom/git-xlsx-textconv) great snippet of code and converted it to Python ([here](https://gist.github.com/nmz787/c43bc109db915064f188)).

In the README, it says to configure/create these files: 
**.gitconfig**

```
[diff "xlsx"]
    binary = true
    textconv = python C:/Python27/Scripts/git-xlsx-textconv.py
```

and **.gitattributes**

```
*.xlsx diff=xlsx
```

I read that you can have repo-level versions of these files, and would like my colleagues using the repo to seamlessly have this functionality after doing the next **pull**

In Windows batch files, you can refer to the file's directory using the keyword **~dp** or in Python using **__file__**... so I'm wondering can I refer to the special diff script (present in the same repo as the repo-level .gitconfig) from the .gitconfig file using some similar special keyword? I'm thinking something like this:

```
**.gitconfig**

[diff "xlsx"]
    binary = true
    textconv = python $REPO_ROOT_OF_THIS_GIT_CONFIG/src/util/git-xlsx-textconv.py
```

where my directory structure looks like this:

```
REPO_ROOT
    .gitconfig
    .gitignore
    .gitattributes
    README.txt
    Requirements.txt
    src
        main.py
        util
            git-xlsx-textconv.py
```

Comment: So I just found that **git rev-parse --show-toplevel** will show the git-repo-root... but I also realized that the **.gitconfig** file only works if it's in the .git directory, so now I guess the question is 

A) does Windows support backticks in command strings like Linux does (so I could write **textconv = python \`git rev-parse --show-toplevel\`/src/util/git-xlsx-textconv.py**)
and 

B) can I commit my .git directory so my colleagues have this feature automatically? (I already read there are security concerns, and could also add a configure script or something to the top-level)

Comment: Grr, first attemp at changing the textconv line to **textconv = python \`git rev-parse --show-toplevel\`/src/util/git-xlsx-textconv.py** didn't work... not sure if it was git or Windows that caused the issue though :(

Comment: Actually I wasn't in the repo, I did **cd ..** one too many times!
Works in **ConEmu**, **cmd** and **git-bash**  
                                             **textconv = python \`git rev-parse --show-toplevel\`/src/util/git-xlsx-textconv.py** Yay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in **ConEmu**, **cmd.exe** and **git-bash** (and I assume Linux):

```
textconv = python `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/src/util/git-xlsx-textconv.py
```